# Help identify 6 pin SMD - top mark MAW - found near BIOS on motherboards and GPUs

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I need help to identify a SMD component of 6 pin, without manufacturer. Only mark "MAW". Seems it is commonly used for BIOS circuit on motherboards and GPUs. I need to replace it by a new one.

Attached an image as example:

[image: photo of components on a PCB]

Comment: I doubt that's a "W". Looks more like a rotated "E" to me. And, without knowing what it does, how would you know that you need to replace it?

Comment: Any chance that could be a SC70-6 capsule? Can you trace any of the pins? Could it be a SiP32431DR3-T1GE3?

Comment: The attached image is not the real target. On the GPU, the IC is displaced from its location (not sure, but seems by a heavy hit), and I am trying to fix it, better if I found a new replacement

Comment: how do you know that the IC is defective? ... are the leads broken off? ... i would think that it is more likely that the PCB traces peeled off the board ... please post a picture of what you are dealing with